# Clang: symbols not found. cocos2d mac

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocos2d-iphone, clang

When i compile my cocos2d mac project i get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
  _ccInflateMemoryWithHint in ZipUtils.o
"_inflate", referenced from:
  _ccInflateMemoryWithHint in ZipUtils.o
"_inflateEnd", referenced from:
  _ccInflateMemoryWithHint in ZipUtils.o
"_gzopen", referenced from:
  _ccInflateGZipFile in ZipUtils.o
"_gzread", referenced from:
  _ccInflateGZipFile in ZipUtils.o
"_gzclose", referenced from:
  _ccInflateGZipFile in ZipUtils.o
"_uncompress", referenced from:
  _ccInflateCCZFile in ZipUtils.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to add the libz.dylib library to your target.

As of Xcode 4.6, this is very easy. The target summary screen lets you add and remove frameworks and libraries.  Here's a demonstration:

[image: adding a library to a target in Xcode 4.6 and later]

Comment: Found this and helped me - now the library is called "libz.tbd"

Answer (score 22):

Open your target's Build Settings. Locate the **Other Linker Flags** setting. Add the **-lz** flag to it.

You don't need to add the libz.dylib as a framework as Rob suggests, although that works too.

Comment: Worked like a charm when trying to build a project using the cocos2d static lib.

Comment: Also works with Cocos2d (templates) as source.  (NOTE: Chipmunk sources had to be `-f-objc-no-arc`-ed.)